# Error al hacer built en unity Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity, deployment, build

Cuando le doy a built en unity me sale el siguiente error, pienso que es porque estoy usando Firebase, pero no se como solucionarlo.
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.18f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\net471\il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

tenía el mismo problema cuando añadí firabase a mi proyecto y el error era porque  estaba eliminando archivos que me marcaba como "obsoletos" al momento de añadir el package de firabase [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posiblemente tu error sea el mismo, si es así solamente dale en cancelar cuando te aparezca la ventana que se muestra en la imagen

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu respuesta y describir brevemente qué ventana es la que se muestra (y a la que hay que darle _cancelar_)? Ten en cuenta que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.